# $\Gamma(X,)$ is not an exact functor.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I prove the following, is it correct?

> Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$. Let $Y$ be a closed subset $\{p,q\} \subset
>  \mathbb{P}^1$.  Let $\mathcal{I}_Y$ be a sub-sheaf of the sheaf of
>   regular functions $\mathcal{O}_X$ on $X$ which vanishes on $Y$.
>
> Consider a short exact swquence.
>
> $0 \to \mathcal{I}_Y \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{F} \to 0$.
>
> Show that $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{F})$ is not
>   surjective.

A PROOF.

Because if  $p \notin Y$, then  $\mathcal{I}_{Y,p}$ =  $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$, the we get  $\mathcal{F}=i_p(\mathcal{O_p}) +i_q(\mathcal{O_q})$, where $i_p(A)$ denotes the skyscraper sheaf  of a ring  $A$, namely,   $i_p(A)(U)=A$ if $p \in U$ and zero for otherwise.

Then, 
$\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) = \Gamma( \mathbb{P},\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}) =  \mathbb{C}$ and $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{F} ) =   \mathbb{C} + \mathbb{C}$.

Because there is no surjection $ \mathbb{C} \to\mathbb{C} + \mathbb{C}$,

$\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{F})$ is not surjective.

Comment: Redaction is a bit awkward, but the proof is correct.